# How to pass variables into a filter on a recordset or collection

Tags: php, lithium

So I have a variable and a recordset:

```
$firstRecordID = 1;
$records = Recordset::all();
```

I want to filter the recordset:

```
$filteredRecords = $records->find(function($record){
    if($record->id == $firstRecordID)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
});
```

Unfortunately, the closure has no clue what $firstRecordID is.

How do I pass in the ID?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can bind the $firstRecordID to the closure:

```
$firstRecordID = 1;
$records = Recordset::all();

$filterFunction = function ($record) use ($firstRecordID) {
    return ($record->id == $firstRecordID);
};

$filteredRecords = $records->find($filterFunction);
```

I also simplified your lambda into a single line.

Answer (score 1):

It is maybe a stupid question, but why are you getting everything to filter afterwards manually when the ODM can do that directly?

```
$records = Recordset::all(array(
    'conditions' => array(
        'id' => array('<>' => $firstRecordID)
    )
));
```

Even if the result isn't much smaller that doing `all()` it looks much cleaner using the right tool for the right purpose.

Comment: I agree, but the example was for simplicity's sake. I need this because the condition for $firstRecord is not known during compile time. Multiple conditions are actually embedded into each row, decided by the user, following a certain format, and when a certain event happens, my closure will use the information in the row to decide what rows will need to be selected.